# Accessing variable from other class returns null

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, null, return

I did a separate levelData class to be able to flexibly add levels. I was happy with it until my supervisor ordered me to convert my levelData into XML. I did an XML version of the levelData's data (question, answers, correct answer...). I used the old class and converted it so that it fetches the XML.

All seems well, I did traces of my answers array and it printed nicely...

But the headache started when I tried this.

```
// This code appears in a different class with
// currentLvl:LevelData initialized in the constructor.
quizHolder.ansA.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[1];
quizHolder.ansB.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[2];
quizHolder.ansC.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[3];
quizHolder.ansD.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[4];
// BTW, I can't make a for loop to do the same function as above. So wierd.
```

I tried to run it. it returned:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at QuestionPane/setQuiz()
    at QuestionPane/setQuestion()
    at QuestionPane()
    at LearningModule()
```

Where did I go wrong? I tried making a custom get function for it, only to get the same error. Thanks in advance. If I need to post more of the code, I will gladly do so =)

LevelData Class in PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/aTKC1sBC

Comment: It would be interesting how the class `LevelData` look like.

Comment: EDIT: Added a Pastebin link. I don't want to scare anyone by the length XD

Comment: Can you also supply your QuestionPane class and the class that instantiates LevelData if different?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code it's hard to diagnose, but did you correctly initialize the choices Array before using it?  Failing that I think you'll need to post more code.

Another possible issue is the delay in loading the XML data. Make sure your data is set before QuestionPane tries to access it.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the constructor. And there is an EventListener that delays the code until full-load. =) Please check out the pastebin link. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

When did you call

```
quizHolder.ansA.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[1];
quizHolder.ansB.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[2];
quizHolder.ansC.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[3];
quizHolder.ansD.ansHud.text = currentLvl.choices[4];
```

these? You load the XML and on complete you fill the array, what is correct. but is the XML loaded and parsed to the time when you access (fill the TextFields) the choices array already?

Comment: After I initialized the LevelData object in the class. I called two chain methods just after LevelData's initialization. Is the setLevelData method in the LevelData class enough to parse the XML data? The     trace(choices[index]); within the setLevelData method outputs the answers right... Or is that where I did it wrong...?

Comment: No, this will cost at least 1 frame ore more. All your functions will be called in the current frame.

Comment: I am sorry to say, I didn't get the frames thingy. What should I be editing?

Comment: Okay ;-) flash always uses its frame paradigma. so most events from loading will be executed after a frame is drawn. all subsquent code will be executed in a single frame. A bit hard to describe, but you have to wait explicitly for the loaded event of the XML in all cases. You may have to extend your `LevelData` from  `EventDispatcher` and add a listener to your `LevelData` instance. In `LevelData` fire an event if parsing is complete. After that you can use your instance as you wish to.

Comment: I tried it, and added an EventListener so that I am sure that I only set the TextFields after a full parse. But it won't execute. T_T

Comment: Sry, but I do not know enough about your complete project to help any further -.-